# Parse email fields with Golang

Tags: email, parsing, go

I am trying to parse my emails in Go and I need help.

How to get access to Content-type field of mail?

```
    cmd, _ = c.Fetch(set, "BODY[HEADER]", "BODY[1]")
    for cmd.InProgress() {
    for _, rsp = range cmd.Data {
        header := imap.AsBytes(rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["BODY[HEADER]"])
        body := imap.AsString(rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["BODY[1]"])
        if msg, _ := mail.ReadMessage(bytes.NewReader(header)); msg != nil {
```

with this I can gain access to Body and Header, but when email contain included file then with `BODY[1]` I have all meta-data, not only pure text. To avoid that I can use `BODY[1.1]`, but I need condition by `Content-Type:[multipart/alternative]` and I can't gain access ot that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i figured it out by my self. But anyway, maybe someone else interested in that. You can have access to varios fields of mail by

```
msg.Header.Get("Content-type")
```

and instead of `Content-type` you can put any header part name.

```
fmt.println(msg)
```

to know what name fields it have